# Parameter order issue when using stored procedure

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 9 - I've built a report which basically uses a stored procedure and has 3 parameters: A, B, C which are also prompts in the report.  I also have prompts D, and E which are *not* passed to the stored procedure.  When I run this report normally (through CR9) the prompts appear in the correct, and expected order: A, B, C, D, E.  However, my customers are experiencing odd behavior when using the crystal reports viewer: the order of prompts showing is: D, E, A, B, C.  I am not sure if this is a bug: I have tried re-adding the prompts by first deleting them all and then re-adding the prompts in the order that I want them to show up, but they *still* see the incorrect order.  I have also attempted to get them to update their viewer version, and they see the same problem.

Also note that it is not sorting the promts (in the viewer) alphabetically.  My example is just for the sake of argument.

Why would the viewer show the prompts in a different order?  This problem only seems to exist when I link to a stored procedure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible in your report, but try here's a couple of suggestions:

1. Use groups
2. use a series of sub reports (one for each prompt after "A")

Comment: but how would this impact the order of the prompts?

Comment: Using sub reports would allow you to pull the information you need for each prompt, in the order you would want it.  So, prompt "A" would give you the information on the main report inside of group "A", "B" would then be it's own sub report within group footer "A"1, "C" would be it's own sub report within group footer "A"2...

Comment: I am talking about the order of the prompts actually presented to the user prior to running the report (not the order of appearance within the report itself)

Comment: Sorry I thought how it was showing was incorrect.  I know it's showing correctly when you run the report, but is what the user see's showing the order that they are located in under the field exploer?  If they show the way you see them the only thing I can think of is try un-checking the "Save with Data" option, save & close the report.  Reopen the report, recheck the "Save with Data" and save the report again.  See if that corrected the issue.

Comment: If the parameter's are ordered in the Field Explorer the way that user see's them.  They will need to be reordered.  I'm not sure how to do that inside of CR9, in CR10 you can right click on the parameter and move to where you would like.

Comment: In the field explorer they can be re-ordered, but for whatever reason they do not show up correctly when using the crystal viewer - I think there is a bug\glitch in there somewhere that is somehow forcing the parameters to be presented differently.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just choose the `Stored Procedure` from `Database Expert` and clicked on it, setting the Report Source.

You could, instead:

- Open `Database Expert`
- click `Add Command`
- add the parameters you need in correct order (A, B, C but also D,E that are not needed by stored procedure) from the right panel
- Type a query similar to this `Exec MyStoredProcedure ('{?ParamA}','{?ParamB}', {?ParamC} );`
  [If param is string *(ParamA, ParamB)* you need to encapsulate with `'`, if it's numeric *(ParamC)* you don't have to encapsulate ]

Parameters will be :

- **prompt to user in the right order**
- **passed to the stored procedure if needed**
- **available inside report logic, if needed**

Comment: This is a very good suggestion: unfortunately, there are some limitations such as the fact that I cannot reorder the parameters myself (they seem to be in forced alphabetical order) and this is somewhat of a deal-breaker.  As I said A,B,C,D,E was an example, the aren't to be shown alphabetically.

Comment: It would also seem as though Param D and Param E are removed if they are not used.

Comment: It's just a workaround, but you could us a prefix for params til you find a solution: 1- ParamB, 2- ParamE, 3-ParamA and so on

Comment: I thought of that, but it is inconsistent with other reports (part of why the ordering is a problem in the first place).  Thanks for the suggestion, though.